# How can the multiplicative number (n) of a chemical series like polyethylene glycol (PEG) be a non-integer?

Tags: organic-chemistry, polymers, chemical-formula

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/PEG_400

Down at chemical or molecular formula, it says:

C_2n H_4n+2 O_n+1, like for all polyethylene glycols (PEG)s, but then says n=8.2 to 9.1....

Huh?

Comment: What surprises you, exactly? What do you think $n$ here is, and why should it necessarily be an integer number?

Comment: [Please don't post links to the mobile versions of the website](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4358). Please visit [this page](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/notation), [this page](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/443/) and [this one](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/86/) on how to format your future posts better with MathJax and Markdown.